# How to visualize multivariate time series dataset

Tags: python, pandas, plot, time-series, data-visualization

I have time series data containing 100 features. (these are all meaningful features, so I cannot reduce the size anymore)

What is the best way to visualize these features distributions to find out the patterns ?

If I plot all dataframe columns separately, there are too many graphs.
And If I I plot all columns on single graph, I cannot see the details since the graph size is not big enough.

Can you provide some sample codes with details ?

Thank you for your help.

e.g.
[image]

Comment: Is size E paper out of the question?  Zooming and Panning?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by making a pairplot. Seaborn is a good library for this. You can see some starter code and sample outputs in the documentation:

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html

You might want to break it up a bit. One-hundred features is too many to realistically fit onto one plot.